# home page goes back to default when changing store

Tags: configuration, language, stores, theme-fallback

I have setup a website with 2 stores (english and welsh). I am usng a custom built layout,template and skin.

When I attempt to change language (home page only) the home page reverts to the base fallback and just displays "home page" and the paypal image, my header and footer remain intact.

Through troubleshooting I have checked the backend config and both stores for all aspects of config refer to the "use website" fallback and my default setup points to my custom template.

It only the home page it seems to be happening on so i know its a fallback issue with the template but i cant figure it out, any help will be much appreciated, if you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was going on.

Within the **`cms.xml`** layout file the default index was pointing towards the `1 column.phtml` template but the cms_page block was pointing to the `content_heading.phtml`, once I added the correct template to the cms_page block it worked